# h.264 I-frame loss handling in rtsp streaming

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp, live555

I am developing a player which open rtsp stream using Live555 and using FFMPEG to decode video stream. I am stuck at a point, where IDR frame is getting lost over the network, so that after decoding its successor B/P frames, it shows a jittering effect in video. It gives a very bad performance in video.

So my question is, How can I handle I-frame packet loss? I would like to know if there is any strategy/algorithm to handle packet loss, so that video should be smooth or clear.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once an I-frame is lost, it's lost. You can't really do anything on the client side. The only way we could attack this problem was to configure the server (ie: streamer) in a way that it will send either more frequently I-frames (ie: MORE I-frames in a stream)  or more infrequent I-frames (ie_ LESS I-frames in  the stream) (if you use ffmpeg/libx264 it can be fine tuned to an incredible level of precision when to send I-frames).

Comment: How can I come to know that, I-frame is lost? There are 2 streams which streams in diff patterns. Like one camera with 7,8,6,5,1,1,1,1,1.....7,8,6,5,1,1.. and another stream with this pattern 6,5,6,1,1,6,1,1,6,1,1...,6,5,6,1,1,... If I frame is lost, should I skip its next dependent frames and stop decoding till I get next I-frame?

Comment: I think that you need to synchronize somehow your player's I-frame request with the streamer's I-frame output. Such as if you configure the streamer to output constantly 1 I-frame after every 4th B-frame (yes, the encoder is not requested to do this, however it can be forced / and these are just numbers not related to anything/) and you start counting your frames you easily can detect one lost I-frame. And the decision what to do is up to you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a first approach, I guess you decode the frame synchronously, I mean the Live555 afterGetting callback call directly the avcodec_decode_video2 of FFMPEG.

In such case the receiving socket is not read during decoding, then packets are buffered till it overflow.

You can try different workaround like increasing the socket buffer, using RTP over TCP, but a real solution need to be more asynchronous, for instance afterGetting can push data to a fifo and the decoding thread can get from it.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion, this is way I have implemented a code for player. But I am concern about the network packet loss, its handling and getting smother video.

Comment: In order to play video smoothly, you need to implement a jitter filter. See for instance http://www.ind.rwth-aachen.de/en/research/speechaudio-communication/voice-over-ip/adaptive-jitter-buffer/. This is for audio, but the problem is the same for video.